# jwplayer call event on 80 percent of video

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Im using jwplayer to handle the videos on my site, but having difficulty figuring out how to fire an event on a certain percentage of the video.

This is my current code:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "video.mp4",
    height: 600,
    width: 600,
    events: {
        onComplete: function() {
            alert("hi!");
        }
    }
});
```

which fires an event only on complete. I want to fire the even when the video hits 80 percent completion.

Any tips?

Comment: I would look into using onTime for this.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer how would I dynamically get the time position of the 80% mark

Comment: get the `lenght` of the video and `current` time then `progress` = current time X lenght / 100 whene progress >=80 fire your fine

Comment: progress should be in an event like playing

Comment: Read this: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

Comment: so have you seen my answer?

Comment: That works, great solution, will upvote!

Answer (score 2):

here is your solution on [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k3rnel31/9PGgn/7/)

the problem is you can not get the `duration` of the video only `current duration`

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
file: "video.mp4",
height: 600,
width: 600,
   });
```

if your video length is 5:00 so `durationtofire`  = 4;

```
var durationtofire = 4;
jwplayer("myElement").onTime(function(event) {
   if (event.position > durationtofire) {
    alert("we are on 80%");
}
});
```